# RestKit - Map to a simple instance variable

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20, objective-c-2.0

I am quite new to RestKit. I know that the Object Mapping of Restkit is very powerful. However, in some case, I just want to map to a simple variable. For example, take a look at the following response:

```
{
    "response": 400,
    "result": {
        "error_message": "Invalid session token"
    }
}
```

I just want to know the value of "response" or "error_message". It's quite wasteful to create 2 classes "response", and "result", since these classes have only few fields.

Any recommendation is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single class with `response` and `message` properties, then use mappings:

```
@"response" : @"response",
@"result.error_message" : @"message"
```

Or you can just map into a dictionary for error responses and then use the keypath to access the message.